# Default Drive/Volume icon... where can I find it?

Tags: icon

So I went into `/System/Libary/CoreServices` and I `find . '*.icns'`, and while I found many *alternative* drive icons, I could not find the default silver and orange drive icons! I need these to make a custom icon for a drive of mine. Does anybody know where this might be?

Edit: I went into `/System/Library` and just did a `find` there. The closest I could find was `./PreferencePanes/StartupDisk.prefPane/Contents/Resources/StartupDisk.icns` but that's the startup disk icon not the removable media icon.

Answer (score 1):

I found it at:

```
/System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/Removable.icns
```